# Do I need more than one master page for my case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, webforms

I have two types of pages .. the first is a display list and the second is a form to collect data.

I used a master page with two panels and each panel contains a ContentPlaceHolder .. the first contenet holder will show the input controls and the second one will show a unique message for every page after the user submit his data.

This is sort of a web moderator panel, where he'll add and display the items in the system to manage the website.

Now the problem is the second type of pages isn't related to the first type (Collecting data page) in the content area but it will share the same main menu and side menu!

so do I use two MasterPages and repeat the markup of the Main Menu and the Side Menu ? or can I use a base master page and the 2 master will inherit from it or what!!

I'm really confused on how to achieve this without breaking the good design concepts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a master page that has all the main layout information. Then have two sub master pages that inherit the main master page. These pages would just have minimal markup and inherit most of their layout / etc from the main master page

Comment: Ok this makes sense .. but how can I create a master page that uses a master page !? .. I'm using VS 2010 btw

Comment: just like when you create a new page, when you select master page, check the box that says "use master page"

Comment: Thanks (Y) .. but just one thing when using VS 2010, the main master page will be created normally, but the two sub-MastePages that will inherit from the main master page will be of type "Nested Master Page" instead of the ordinary "Master Page".

Comment: Ah sorry - it's been a while. glad you found it though.